# Why utf8mb4 on mysql DB, Table, column gives error on inserting special characters?

Tags: python, mysql, collation, utf8mb4

`MySQL` version is:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.40, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

I have set `utf8mb4` on `database`, `table`, `column` by using commands below:

```
ALTER DATABASE my_db CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

And mysql reports that:

```
mysql> show create database my_db;
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database | Create Database                                                     |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| my_db    | CREATE DATABASE `my_db` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 */   |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And also table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
```

`Mysql` reports that:

```
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14894 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Now the field itself also converted by:

```
ALTER TABLE my_tbl MODIFY body mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

It reports that:

```
  `body` mediumtext
```

It all seems OK. When I connect to `mySQL` through python I set collation:

```
   my_connection.set_character_set('utf8mb4')
```

Now when I insert data the error reports that:

```
OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x9E</...' for column 'body' at row 1")
```

Why it gives an error like that? How should I solve this problem? Or is there any workaround for this?

---

Edit part-1:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_tbl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `for_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `uid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `rec_type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=112774 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

The above character set is on my table. In front of no column I can see collation type. As I said before I have issue the command `Modify` command. Is there something wrong here?

In `my.cnf` I have set the belows and restarted mysql:

```
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
skip-character-set-client-handshake

[client]
default-character-set   = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set   = utf8mb4
```

Comment: What is the character that you are inserting?

Comment: @PankajSinghal How should I set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set_character_set` is one of three things to set.

More on Python:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python  (but use `utf8mb4` where that says `utf8`).

Check that the column is really set to utf8mb4:  Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: On my cursor I have set `my_cursor.execute("SET NAMES utf8mb4;")` before executing the real insert command. All is done now :)